# How to install python package into a docker service inside of a monorepo

Tags: python, docker, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build, monorepo

I have a monorepo setup such as the following:

```
/serviceA
/serviceB
/packageA
/packageB
```

I would like to install `packageA` inside of `serviceA`, which is docker container with a python service inside.

Inside of my `serviceA` `requirements.txt` file I can reference the local package: `file:///Users/me/dev/platform/packageA`, this fails when submitting to `gcloud builds` as the package is not on that machine.

My question is, what are my options here and am I going about this setup the correct/best way?

My thinking is that I could try and copy the code into the docker, but this seems a little hacky - as I am not sure where the version would go..

The other option is to push to GH first and reference from there, but this would mean I need to somehow grant access to the repo to cloud build.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Docker multi stage build](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/) strategy:

```
FROM base as package-builder
COPY your_package_A_code
RUN your_package_build_stuff

FROM base
COPY --from=package-builder /path/builded/package_A /path/to/package_A
```

This way you don't expose the code of your package A inside the service A. Then, reference your package_A where you decide to store (in my example:`/path/to/package_A`) in your `requirements.txt`.

Comment: This looks excellent! Thanks! Any more refs or pointers for `your_package_build_stuff` step?

Comment: You're welcome, you can follow this guide https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/, where the step will probably contain `python3 -m build` command. Then just copy the dist generated output to your main container.

Comment: Thanks again! One last comment/question which is a little open ended - but would you say this is a good way to handle code sharing inside of a monorepo? Versioning seems like an issue here?